# HTML email is showing as code rather than the css page

Tags: php, html, css, email

I wanted to make an automated html/css email, where I have used the `mail()` function but it is showing as code

I have provided the doctype and stuff in the header but still it is showing as code:

[image]

I also concatenated the header giving the doctype into the header but it still doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<?php


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
$email_from = "info@domain.com";
    $email_message = "

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' style='line-height: inherit;'>
<head>

<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<meta content='width=device-width' name='viewport'>

<meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>

<title></title>


<style id='media-query' type='text/css'>
@media only screen and (min-width: 670px) {
  .block-grid {
    width: 650px !important;
  }


  .desktop_hide {
    display: block !important;
    max-height: none !important;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body class='clean-body' style='line-height: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;'>
<style id='media-query-bodytag' type='text/css'>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</
</table>
</body>
</html>";


$to = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Enquiry";
$txt = $email_message;
$headers1="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>";
$headers2 = "From:". $email_from . "\r\n" .
"CC: email@gmail.com";
$headers=$headers1.$headers2;

if (mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers))
{
    //echo "Thank You for contacting us, we will get back to you soon";
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you using to send out the email?

Comment: the php file gets executed and send the email, the files are save in cpanel based hosting

Comment: Im not sure you need to include an html 'page' header, try just setting the content, same you would with smtp and stuff
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

Comment: Also a note: you have an extraneous "</ " between your final table tags. Also, you never apparently open your table. After your "<style>" tag on line 39, your code might make more sense to say `
<table>
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
`
If you are adding information to the body in another place and using this as a template, it might be worth clarifying that since random HTML tags might cause unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to set the Mime and Content Type to send a message containing HTML. Add the following to $headers.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the header to support html email template. Add this code in header.

```
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```